# Different SQL selection based on inter-record condition

Tags: sql, oracle, date, group-by, max

I have a table that holds allocations of problem reports (PRs) as follows:

```
TABLE "ALLOCATIONS"

ALLOCATIONID    PRID    DATEALLOCATED        ENG_ID
1               401     20-SEP-06 10.48.00   1
2               401     20-SEP-06 10.48.00   2
3               401     20-SEP-06 10.48.00   2
4               402     20-SEP-06 12.35.00   1
5               402     20-SEP-06 12.43.00   1
6               402     20-SEP-06 13.43.00   2
7               700     14-OCT-12 13.30.05   1
8               700     14-OCT-12 13.30.35   2
9               700     14-OCT-12 14.30.35   2
```

The most recent allocation determines which engineer the PR is now assigned to. I want to find all the PRs that are assigned to engineer 2 for example.
So I look for the most recent allocation for each PRID, check the ENG_ID, then pull out the information from this table if the ENG_ID is correct.

This table contains the actual PR descriptions (and other info omitted here for clarity).

```
TABLE "PROBLEMS"

PRID     TITLE
401      Something
402      Something
700      Something
```

To do this I have used the DATEALLOCATED field as follows:

```
SELECT PRID, TITLE FROM PROBLEMS p WHERE p.PRID IN
(
    SELECT GROUPEDALLOC.PRID FROM allocations alloc INNER JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT PRID, MAX(DATEALLOCATED) AS MaxAllocationDate    
        FROM allocations   
        GROUP BY PRID
    ) 
    groupedAlloc ON alloc.PRID = groupedAlloc.PRID 
    AND ALLOC.DATEALLOCATED = groupedAlloc.MaxAllocationDate 
    AND ENG_ID = 2
) 
ORDER BY PRID DESC;
```

Now this works fine for records 7,8,9 above which were inserted with a long date format that includes the seconds, however for the older records which didn't log the seconds this will obviously not work. For these records I want to fall back on the allocationID (which may or may not be sequential obviously - however it is a last resort and better than nothing).

My question is, how do I modify my query to perform this extra condition on the DATEALLOCATED (i just want to see if they are all equal for a particular PRID), and then use the ALLOCATIONID instead?

I am using OracleXE but I want to stick to standard SQL if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do it for you ?

```
WITH 
  BY_DATE
  AS (SELECT PRID, MAX (DATEALLOCATED) AS MAXDATE FROM ALLOCATIONS GROUP BY PRID),

  BY_ALLOC
  AS (SELECT A.PRID, MAXDATE, MAX (ALLOCATIONID) AS MAXALLOC
        FROM ALLOCATIONS A JOIN BY_DATE B ON 
             A.PRID = B.PRID AND 
             A.DATEALLOCATED = B.MAXDATE
      GROUP BY A.PRID, MAXDATE)

SELECT A.PRID, A.ENG_ID
  FROM ALLOCATIONS A JOIN BY_ALLOC B ON 
       A.ALLOCATIONID = B.MAXALLOC;
```

Comment: No I don't want to rely on allocationID in case it changes, I only want to use it in the cases where I cannot differentiate the dates for entries with the same PRID.

Comment: I believe the query does just that.  Have you tested it ?

Comment: Are you clear on what the 'HAVING' clause does in the query above ?

Comment: @JamesCarr - are you still interested in this issue?

Comment: Yes I have, it is complaining that it is not a GROUP BY expression. I will try refactoring it using your suggestion though. I also need to add that eng_id must be X.

Comment: This looks like it is exactly what is needed, however just the following segment gets complaints from ORACLE: `SELECT PRID, MAX(DATEALLOCATED), MAX(ALLOCATIONID)
FROM ALLOCATIONS
GROUP BY PRID
HAVING DATEALLOCATED = MAX(DATEALLOCATED);` - ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression. This is confusing because afaik it looks ok.

Comment: @JamesCarr Yes, but its not ok.  This problem got me annoyed so I have tried it out properly on a test system and have come up with a solution for you - please see my latest edit.

Comment: Nice one Hugh you nailed it. All I had to add was "WHERE ENG_ID=X" to the last select and it produces the expected results.

Comment: @JamesCarr - sorry it took so long.  The basic observation was that MAX(ALLOCATIONID) is neutral where there is only one record, so sort the date first then get the MAX(ALLOCATIONID).  May I ask a favour? Could you have a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96277/36/0 and tell me what you can see ?